# Extract object from NSArray without an index

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray

I have an `NSMutableArray` called result with the following objects in this format:

```
Contents of results  : {(
    (0x073BCE60) EAN13: 0710425390128 -- (0 finds)
)}
```

I need to extract 0710425390128 from it but without an index I cannot figure out how this is achieved.

Is there away to modify the `NSMutableArray` to add an index?
Or is there a method to determine an index of sorts for this item (if that makes any sense)?

The item I wish to extract will be different each time results is created.

Thanks

---

I have tried to create an `NSDictionary` from the array results using id objectInstance;

```
NSUInteger indexKey = 0; 
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
for (objectInstance in results) {
    [mutableDictionary setObject:objectInstance forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:indexKey++]]; 
}
```

With formats the data in to

```
{ "Scanned Items" = ( "(0x0733A120) EAN13: 0710425390128 -- (0 finds)" ); "Session End Time" = "2012-05-25 01:23:55 +0000"; }
```

Still lost on how to assign the values keys.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDictionary`. Using a `key` , you can retrieve an `object`. Please refer to the  [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)   !

Comment: My app is not creating the array. So the format is what I have to work with. Yes, I can create an NSDictionary but I am struggling to do so and assign the elements a key value! The documentation is a great asset, if you know where to look in the first place and having read it to extensively I am still not sure how to resolve this. Which is why I hoped for some pointers here. But anyway.....thanks....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by: *"Is there away to modify the Mutable Array to add an index"*

To access an object in an array at a given index use:

```
[myArray objectAtIndex: someIndex];
```